# C case-switch statement not running through full loop

Tags: c, for-loop, char, switch-statement

Trying to solve a problem on kattis.com called "Bela", which requires some character comparison, but when i run my code the scanf() function does not get called the last couples time for the last couple iterations of the loop.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {`


    char dom;
    int n;
    scanf("%d %c", &n, &dom);
    n*=4;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            char num;
            char suit;
            scanf("%c%c", &num, &suit);

            switch (num) {

                    case 'A':
                            sum += 11;
                            break;
                    case 'K':
                            sum += 4;
                            break;
                    case 'Q':
                            sum += 3;
                            break;
                    case 'J':
                            if (suit == dom) { sum +=20;}
                            else { sum += 2;}
                            break;
                    case 'T':
                            sum+=10;
                            break;
                    case '9':
                            if (suit == dom){sum+=14;}
                            break;
                    case '8':
                            break;
                    case '7':
                            break;
                    default:

                            continue;

            }
    }

    printf("%d", sum);




    return 0;


}
```

and when i run the with this test case program i get this:

```
:~$ ./a.out
^V
2 S
TH
9C
KS
QS
JS
TD3
AD
JH
:~$ TD
TD: command not found
:~$ AD
AD: command not found
:~$ JH
JH: command not found
```

why is the for loop not executing completely? Is there anyhting inherently wrong with my code that the switch case statement does not evaluate "TD", "AD", "JH"?

Comment: What have you done to investigate / debug this issue?  How did you conclude that the switch statement is the problem?  Did you attempt to test exactly what values were input by printing them out again or examining them in a debugger?  If you do this, you're likely to find that a newline character is getting in there.  And then you can begin to consider why.

Comment: I bet `scanf("%c%c", &num, &suit);` leaves `num` containing `'\n'` (just a hunch...)

Answer (score 1):

> why is the for loop not executing completely?

Add `printf("\nEnter:");` before second scanf check it. The loop execute fully but the scanf catches spaces.

So,

Add

```
 while((ch=getchar()!='\n')&&ch!=EOF);
```

Before the second scanf or change second scanf to

```
 scanf(" %c%c", &num, &suit);
        ^
```

This statements are ignore spaces`(' ','\n',...)`